# QNetworkReply - Strange error in enum, OperationCanceled instead of Timeout?

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkreply

My API server is turned off and i run following code.
I dont understand why QNetworkReply::OperationCanceledError error enum is returned instead of QNetworkReply::TimeoutError. What is wrong? Am i doing something wrong or is it Qt bug?

From documentation that error should be if "the operation was canceled via calls to abort() or close() before it was finished."
I see no reason for that.

```
QByteArray encodedData = data.toUtf8();
QUrl url("http://myapi/jsonrpc");
QNetworkRequest request(url);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");

QNetworkAccessManager manager;
manager.setTransferTimeout(500);
QNetworkReply* reply = manager.post(request, encodedData);

QEventLoop loop;
connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
loop.exec();

if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
    QString errorMsg = QString("HTTP Network request has failed. Code: ") + QVariant::fromValue(reply->error()).toString();
    delete reply;
    // error
    // here i got QNetworkReply::OperationCanceledError
}

QByteArray response = reply->readAll();
//ok
```

Comment: When you say that the "server is turned off", do you mean that the hardware itself is turned off? Or that the program wasn't running to begin with? Something else?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yep hardware itself and whole connection in Windows is marked as "cable disconnected". Even if it was caused by server i would expect some connection closed by remote or connection refused. But not this strange Qt error which shoud be related to abort or close methods on my side.